How to give gradient effect in animation stroke? Everything has been done, but it's not happening
,,,
https://codepen.io/intelli2018/pen/MWRGVpw (Demo)
Above is the demo for what I tried to develop on CodePen.
Please have a look image I am working on this.....
Reference image for Gradient line effect....
Please have a look image I am working on this.....
Reference image for Gradient line effect....

